# Can someone explain this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, function, oop

I am trying to understand how this code works. I finally figured out it is a loop. It is not a "while" or "for" loop, but it is a loop nonetheless by virtue of calling itself I think (please correct me if I am wrong).

I understand it's main function: to pass JQuery when it is loaded to my 'foo' function, when ever jQuery has loaded. To do that it checks for jQuery in `Window` and if not there it resets the `timer()`. That is the loop. I get that.

Let me explain what I do not understand:

1. the call: `CheckDependency.Deferred.execute(foo);`

   - why the "Deferred" keyword?
   - `execute` baffles me: I expect that if I call `CheckDependency.Deferred.execute` that it would only execute that method. Why does it obviously run the timer function. why could it not simply have that code after the timer() since it keeps looping there and then return jquery?
2. Speaking of return. Why is there a method in there?  `CheckDependency.Deferred.execute(foo);` is as crazy to me as `CheckDependency.Deferred.RETURN.execute(foo);` (or some similar crazy statement)

I am fairly new to JavaScript (from PHP). Here the code:

```
function foo(){ console.log('jQuery found!');
} 
var CheckDependency = CheckDependency || { };
CheckDependency.Deferred = function () 
{
    var functions = [];
    var timer = function() {
        if (window.jQuery) {/* && window.jQuery.ui*/
            while (functions.length) {
                functions.shift()(window.jQuery);
            }
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(timer, 250);
        }
    };
    timer();
    return {
    execute: function(onJQueryReady) 
    {
        if (window.jQuery) { // && window.jQuery.ui
            onJQueryReady(window.jQuery);
        } else {
            functions.push(onJQueryReady);
        }
    }
  };
}();
CheckDependency.Deferred.execute(foo);
```

Comment: It's pretty straight forward, `execute` is a function that runs when you call it. It looks like its waiting for a jQuery instance.

Comment: Google for suitable tutorials

Comment: Do you understand what `CheckDependency.Deferred = function ()  {...}()` does?

Comment: @PM77-1 I understand it's main function: to pass JQuery to my 'foo' function, when ever jQuery has loaded.

Comment: @PM77-1  Ah yes, it is a self executing function ..trailing ()

Comment: @Shanimal - I did not know one could call a method defined after a return statement. Could you explain what is the intent/technique here. I would have put it before the return and return the JQuery object it found.

Comment: @PeterSmith Peter what would I search for specifically please?

Comment: In JavaScript function is an object that can be returned from another function.

Comment: That's called hoisting. When you define `function x(){}`, x is available anywhere in that scope. But that's not what's happening here. The return statement is returning an object with the execute function. Deferred is now the instance of that object.

Comment: I can't really call this code straightforward, given its recursive nature and its uses of closure and timer. But by breaking it down step by step, of course it is possible to understand what it does. But for a beginner, that's definitely not a simple case. so some comments here are not very explanatory when not out of line. Alex, Javascript has these things, it is a matter of getting used to them, welcome to SO and don't hesitate to ask your questions.

Comment: im confused why you're not just putting jquery ahead of your script in the document `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>`

Comment: @user3743222 Thanks!

Comment: @Shanimal I am not actually loading jQuery, I am just making sure it is available to my script before I make jQuery calls. The way this bit of found code does helps me is that when jQuery is loaded it pasess it to my function ( onJQueryReady(window.jQuery) and thus my code is not even invoked until that happens.

Comment: @Shanimal Also you might ask: Why not on document ready? Because I am contributing code a page where they load scripts at the footer but my script is in the middle. I am looking into RequireJS which they do use and might be the right solution. I have not learned it yet.

Comment: Maybe the important part that is overlooked here is the self executing function call. When this executes it sets `CheckDependency.Deferred = [self executing function]` to the value the function returns (eg. `{execute:...}`);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start by saying I'm not a javascript expert, but I dabble :)  I'll take a stab at describing what is going on here.

First, This creates a new object called "CheckDependency".

```
var CheckDependency = CheckDependency || { };
```

Next, it runs an anonymous function, and stores the result in CheckDependency.Deferred.

```
CheckDependency.Deferred = function () 
{
    .
    .
    .
    .
}()
```

The anonymous function runs the following code:

```
var functions = [];
var timer = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {/* && window.jQuery.ui*/
        while (functions.length) {
            functions.shift()(window.jQuery);
        }
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(timer, 250);
    }
};
timer();
```

The last part of the function code returns a new function `execute`, which gives `CheckDependency.Deferred` a function `execute`.

```
return {
    execute: function(onJQueryReady) 
    {
       if (window.jQuery) { // && window.jQuery.ui
            onJQueryReady(window.jQuery);
        } else {
            functions.push(onJQueryReady);
        }
    }
  };
```

Finally, this new function is called

```
CheckDependency.Deferred.execute(foo);
```

The final result of this is that the code starts a background timer that calls itself until `window.jQuery` is true - which means `jQuery` is loaded.  Then, the function passed to `execute` is passed into this loop and so will once `jQuery` is available, the original function passed to "execute" will be called with the instance of `window.jQuery`.

I hope I did this justice, and I hope my answer helps!  Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! I get this now! Specially the "**_which gives CheckDependency.Deferred a function execute_**" part.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad I could help :)